# correct way to access node-revision change property in twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have a Drupal 8.9.17 website. My theme (based on [Garland](https://www.drupal.org/project/garland)) includes in `templates/page.html.twig`:

```
{% if node %}
[...]
Last updated {{ node.changed.value|format_date('custom', 'D M d Y') }}
[...]
{% endif %}
```

This displays the property when viewing nodes at: `/node/<nid>`

However, when attempting to view revisions at `/node/<nid>/revisions/<vid>/view`, format_date() fails with "null timestamp" error so I assume that the revision is not being properly loaded.

What is the correct way to access the property so it works at both routes?

Comment: The correct way should be showing it in the *node.html.twig* template file, which is used only for nodes.

Comment: @apaderno is a node-revision not a node?

Comment: @apaderno the page.html.twig has a comment that "Fully load node, if there is an automatially-loaded node" is available. Shouldn't `{% if node %}` catch if this is not the case?

Comment: The *node.html.twig* template is also used for node revisions. The question is about the *page.html.twig* template, which is the template used for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information shown for a node, I prefer the [*node.html.twig*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.9.x) template, as it doesn't require to first check the page is rendered for a node. The *node.html.twig* template already has the following lines.

```
{% if display_submitted %}
  <footer>
    {{ author_picture }}
    <div{{ author_attributes }}>
      {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
      {{ metadata }}
    </div>
  </footer>
{% endif %}
```

If I wanted to change the way the date is rendered, or which date is shown, without removing the other information shown in the template file, I would replace those lines with the following ones.

```
{% if display_submitted %}
  <footer>
    {{ author_picture }}
    <div{{ author_attributes }}>
      {% trans %}Last updated on {{ node.getChangedTime()|format_date('custom', 'D M d Y') }}{% endtrans %}
      {{ metadata }}
    </div>
  </footer>
{% endif %}
```

For the Garland theme, which is now a contributed theme, the part to change is the following one.

```
{% if display_submitted %}
  <span class="submitted">{{ date }} — {{ author_name }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

You can either replace those lines with the following lines, or the next ones, if you just want to change the date format.

```
{% if display_submitted %}
  <span class="submitted">{% trans %}Last updated on {{ node.getChangedTime()|format_date('custom', 'D M d Y') }}{% endtrans %}</span>
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if display_submitted %}
  <span class="submitted">{{ node.getChangedTime()|format_date('custom', 'D M d Y') }} — {{ author_name }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

As the documentation for the *node.html.twig* template says, not all the node properties and methods are accessible via `node`; only the methods whose names start with *get*, *has*, or *is* are available, together a few common methods such as `id`, `label`, and `bundle`.

Comment: This appears to be different from the [Garland node.html.twig](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/garland/-/blob/8.x-1.x/templates/node.html.twig) which does not contain `<footer>`. I'm sure the site will eventually move to a better theme, but I'm stuck with it for now.

Comment: It's not much different: Just look at the line using `{{ date }}` and replace it with the code you need, as the updated answer shows. I was not able to find the Garland theme; I didn't think to look between the contributed themes.

Comment: I just had a closer look at the customised garland I have been given and don't see anything that requires the code to be in page.html.twig, so using node.html.twig does seem like the way to go